# How to find all transaction made by a customer by only one of the mode

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have like below

```
Custid .  Transction Mode
1.        cash
2.        Online
1.        Online
3.        Cash
1.        Cash
```

How to find only cash transactions made by customers

Comment: show your table structure and data.

Comment: you can add a status column in your payment table

Comment: use where clause to get the customer of cash transactions

Comment: Maybe you want like this  `SELECT column1,column2 FROM tablename where model='Cash'`

Comment: I think you should be trying a basic tutorial rather than getting SO to do your homework. Questions of genuine problems are welcome however this is a little bit lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE `Transaction Mode` = 'cash'
```